# Auhenticate a user in laravel to my app object for processing jobs

Tags: laravel

For my models I have saving event that listens whenever a model updates, to save the current user in field `modfied_by`

The problem is that sometimes I need to updated this models from a non http context (where the user is not logged). How can I do something like that

1. auhtneticate in $app as user id 7
2. save the model

Answer (score 0):

You can login any user by his `id`

```
Auth::loginUsingId(7);
```

You can pretty much save the model like how you would normally do it.

```
$model = Model::find($id);
// Do changes
$model->save();
```

Hope this helps.